# Como verificar se um botão está visível?

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber se e possível utilizar um operador de condição, como o if por exemplo, para verificar se um botão  está visível ou não. Se for como posso implementa-lo? Fiz algumas tentativas utilizando o is.Enable porém não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 3):

Se é visibilidade que precisa de testar pode utilizar o método [`getVisibility` da classe View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getVisibility()). O método existe na classe `View` mas como `Button` deriva de `View`, pode utiliza-lo diretamente.

No código ficaria assim:

```
if (meuBotao.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    //código para quando está visivel
}
```

Tem 3 estados de visibilidade que pode testar:

- `View.VISIBLE`
- `View.INVISIBLE`
- `View.GONE`

Documentação para a [classe View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) e para a [classe Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)